# ImportError: cannot import name - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to import some variables from a different `python` file resides in the same directory from a another python file.

I have two files **in the same directory** as below:

`constantvariables.py`

`test.py`

This is how `constantvariables.py` looks like

```
class CONST(object):
    FOO = 1234
    NAMESPACE = "default"
    DEPLOYMENT_NAME = "deployment-test"
    DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME = "banukajananathjayarathna/bitesizetroubleshooter:v1"
    SERVICE_CLUSTER = "deployment-test-clusterip"
    SERVICE_NODEPORT = "deployment-test-nodeport"
    INGRESS_NAME = "deployment-test-ingress"

    def __setattr__(self, *_):
        pass

CONST = CONST()
```

and this is how my `test.py` looks like:

```
import os 
from . import constantvariables


print(constantsvariables.NAMESPACE)
```

But I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 7, in 
>       from . import constantsvariables
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'constantsvariables'

can someone please help me?

Python version I am using `python 2.7.5`

Comment: constantvariables.py vs constantsvariables.py ?

Comment: your file is called one thing, your import says another.

Comment: @ChristianSloper I updated the question but the error is still there. I am using `python 2.7.5`

Answer (score 1):

Make constant file like that constant.py and put inside config folder for proper management.

```
FOO = 1234
NAMESPACE = "default"
DEPLOYMENT_NAME = "deployment-test"
DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME = "banukajananathjayarathna/bitesizetroubleshooter:v1"
SERVICE_CLUSTER = "deployment-test-clusterip"
SERVICE_NODEPORT = "deployment-test-nodeport"
INGRESS_NAME = "deployment-test-ingress"
```

Inside your base directory create main.py file and call the constant inside that.

```
import os 
from config.constants import NAMESPACE, FOO
print(NAMESPACE)
```

Comment: I get an error: **unresolved import `config.constant`**

Comment: In your workspace settings, you can set your python path like this:
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/path/to/your/venv/bin/python",
}

Comment: Where should I have to make this change?

Comment: @JananathBanuka This IDE issue, please google it your error on the basis of IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your constant file as it is, you can write this:

```py
import os 
from constantvariables import CONST

print(CONST.NAMESPACE)
```

Comment: @JananathBanuka The files must be in the same folder for it to work.
If they are in different folders, the import must be corrected.

Comment: Files are in the same folder and this doesn't work. Should I have to set python path or something?